# Swift 5: Status Bar Color Management with Orientation Changes

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

IOS 15, Xcode 13.2.1, Swift 5

I am looking to manage the status bar color in my multiple view controller application.  I have successfully found how to change the status bar color in each controller and in portrait orientation.  The issue is when turned to landscape orientation the status bar goes away, and a rectangle the size of the status bar in portrait mode covers the left side of the navigation area.

Here is my code and ussage:

```
func statusBarColor() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        
        let statusBar2 =  UIView()
        if UIApplication.shared.currentScene?.statusBarManager!.statusBarFrame != nil {
            statusBar2.frame = (UIApplication.shared.currentScene?.statusBarManager!.statusBarFrame)!
            statusBar2.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "BackGroundColor")
            UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.addSubview(statusBar2)
        }
    } else {
        let statusBar2: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        statusBar2.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "BackGroundColor")
    }
}
```

Use:  Call the function in viewWillAppear.

Image of Issue: [status bar in landscape mode (Navigation bar covered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pXnz.png)

Comment: What's the question? I mean, in landscape on an iPhone the status bar _does_ go away; that's just a fact. Meanwhile, you've thrust this extra view in front of everything (wrongly, in my opinion, but that's another matter), and you are not removing it. So how can you be surprised?

Comment: I’m not really that surprised, but I can’t really figure out how to get rid of that extra view or hide it in landscape mode. Also, would be more than happy to try a different methodology, but I’m striking out finding an alternative method. If you know a better way, answering the question with that would be super!

Comment: Well, so far you say you only have code in `viewWillAppear` which _inserts_ the view. Obviously you need code in some other places, such as when you detect that rotation is taking place, and in that place you will need to _remove_ your view if we are rotating to landscape, and _insert_ it again if we are rotating to portrait. However, I think what you are trying to do is arguably a wrong thing to do; the status bar is transparent, meaning it is not intended to have an independent color, real or apparent.

Comment: Thank you Matt.  That was enough of a mental push to allow me to figure out how to hide the view.  In the current version of Xcode the status bar turns black on a tableviewcontroller imbedded in a navigationcontroller.  In addition once I segue to that tableview controller it changes the status bar to black globally so all other viewcontollers have a black status bar until the app is reloaded.  That is why I am doing it this way.

Comment: "In the current version of Xcode the status bar turns black on a tableviewcontroller imbedded in a navigationcontroller" No, it doesn't. The status bar is transparent. It sounds to me like you have a bug and this extra view is just a patch. You should be thinking about the bug instead.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added this to my list of bugs to investigate.  In the mean time, your prompting has indeed allowed me to "patch" the issue.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Cool, ping me if you ever post a question about the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matt in question comments for the prompting I have found a workable answer.  It should be noted that this may be necessary in my app due to an unrelated bug, and this can be considered a patch, not a solution to the bug. This code creates a view with a background color and places it in the statusBar.  The view is hidden when the device is in landscape mode and when leaving the current viewController.

This works in Swift 5, iOS 15, Xcode 13.2.1

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let statusBar1 = UIView()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        statusBarColor()
        statusBar1.isHidden = false
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        statusBar1.isHidden = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            statusBar1.isHidden = true
        } else {
            statusBar1.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    func statusBarColor() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

            self.statusBar1.frame = (UIApplication.shared.currentScene?.statusBarManager!.statusBarFrame)!
            self.statusBar1.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "AccentColor")

            UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.addSubview(statusBar1)

        } else {

           let statusBar2: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
           statusBar2.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "AccentColor")
        }
    }
}
```